# MySql stored procedures is atomic?

Tags: mysql

There are the following stored procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_xxx`(IN InXml varchar(500) character set gbk)
BEGIN

DECLARE result INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE t_error INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE InIP VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE InMac VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE InHard VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE DeviceID INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE dev_sql VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE com_sql VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE rlc_sql VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET t_error=1;

label1:BEGIN
    IF LENGTH(InXml) < 36 THEN
        LEAVE label1;
    END IF;

    SET @InIP = extractvalue(InXml,'/ASM/IP');
    SET @InMac = extractvalue(InXml,'/ASM/MAC');
    SET @InHard = extractvalue(InXml,'/ASM/HardID');

    IF LENGTH(@InMac) < 16 THEN
        LEAVE label1;
    END IF;

    IF LENGTH(@InHard) < 16 THEN
        SET @InHard = @InMac;
    END IF;

    SET @dev_sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO Device SET Mac="',@InMac,'", BootTime=now(), Online=1, LastTime=now(),Type=9999');

    IF LENGTH(@InIP) > 5 THEN
        SET @dev_sql = CONCAT(@dev_sql,', IP="',@InIP,'"');
    END IF;

    START TRANSACTION;

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @dev_sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @DeviceID;

    IF @DeviceID > 0 THEN
            SET @com_sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO Computer SET Hard="',@InHard,'", DeviceID=',@DeviceID);
            SET @rlc_sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO RelationComputer SET DeviceID=',@DeviceID);

            PREPARE stmt2 FROM @com_sql;
            EXECUTE stmt2;

            PREPARE stmt3 FROM @rlc_sql;
            EXECUTE stmt3;
    END IF;

    IF t_error = 1 THEN
        SET result = -1;
       ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        SET result = @DeviceID;
       COMMIT;
    END IF;
END label1;

label2:BEGIN
    SELECT result;
END label2;

END
```

for the most part, everything is fine.

but,

occasional problem, check the binlog:

```
...
begin
INSERT INTO Computer...
commit
begin
INSERT INTO RelationComputer...
commit
```

as you can see.

`INSERT INTO Device ...` not executed, but the last two sql are executed.

(this doesn't happen a lot )

what happened?

kneel for the answer.

Comment: Please add table definitions and sample xml as text.

Comment: the xml:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="gbk"?>
<ASM Version="5.2">
<TradeCode>DevSvcAgent_InsertDev</TradeCode>
<APIVersion>v1.00</APIVersion>
<AppID>MVG</AppID>
<IP>172.27.232.160</IP>
<MAC>90:E8:68:43:77:C1</MAC>
<HardID>hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</HardID>
<DeviceID>705855</DeviceID>
<Result>200</Result>
<ResultDesc>DevSvcAgent_InsertDev Success</ResultDesc>
</ASM>`